# RTC with millisec accuracy on MSP430F6736A

Tags: c, microcontroller, msp430

I´m quite new in this kind of programming.
I need to create a real time count on MSP430F6736A (with millisecond accuracy). I'm creating an app that neeeds to do something in short intervals 
(for example: every 2 seconds turn on LED for 50 milliseconds).

Using Code composer 6.1.1

I was thinking about use of Timer and interrupts but I don´t know if it is possible to count millisec like this. I just read that can be applied on seconds, hours .... If it is possible which clock should I choose?

The other way I thought about was some delay or sleep. Can i sleep uC for a 50 millisec (real time) preciselly?

EDIT
Here´s code. / [Code ][1]/ Using Timer_A, ACLK  and his interrupt to blink LED(just blinking now- same long time torned off- same time turned on).

This code blink led with 2 sec delay.
There is problem that register TA1CCR0 can be max 0xFFFF= 65535 (2 sec for ACLK) 
And for my application i will need scale from 1 sec to 999 sec. (row 6-7 in code). How can I do that? Is it possible?

```
#include <msp430.h> 
#include <msp430f6736.h>

void CfgTA(unsigned long delayCycles)
{
    int t2=2;  // must be variable from 1 to 999
    t2=delayCycles*t2;
    TA1CCTL0 |= CCIE;   //Enable Interrupts on Timer
    TA1CCR0 = t2-1;     //Number of cycles in the timer
    TA1CTL |= TASSEL_1 | MC_1;  //ACLK , UP mode

}

void ledblink()
{
    //LED config
     P4DIR |= BIT6;
     P4OUT &= ~BIT6;

     CfgTA(32768);  //Timer configuration to blink every 1 sec
    while (1)
    {
        _bis_SR_register(LPM3_bits + GIE); //Enter Low Power Mode 3 with interrupts
    }

}


#pragma vector=TIMER1_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A0(void)
{

   P4OUT ^= BIT6;   // Swapping on/off LED
}


int main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer

    ledblink();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the datasheet say? I know many of the STM32 chips have sub-second accuracy for the RTC.

Comment: It is possible to use timer as the input clock frequency may be  much higher than required. But the "how" question will be too broad.

Comment: Not only is perfectly possible to count milliseconds using a timer interrupt, but that is the usual way to go.

Comment: Why do you need it be "precise"? Does it really matter if the LED is on for 50 ms or 50.1 ms or even 51 ms? You probably don't want to use the RTC, which counts seconds using a 32kHz crystal. Using the like ordinary timers would make more sense.

Comment: Use RTC interrupt to put LED on each 2 seconds, use an other timer interrupt to turn LED back off after 50 ms, don't sleep or wait, use interrupts.

Comment: Ross Ridge  - led was only example need it for something else.                               So best way will be use timers with interrupts? Which clock should be the best?

Comment: You need to describe your actual needs, otherwise we can only respond based on the example you gave. It should help focus your question, which is too broad and open ended to be answered as it is.

Comment: Non-specific processor: I usually implement a millisecond free-run interrupt anyway, which maintains a `volatile` counter which other processes can use as a clock, or for delays, etc.

Comment: Have a look at the [MSP Design Workshop](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP_Design_Workshop).

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code directly as text.